# How to set required claims for IdentityServer4 API Resources?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, identityserver4, asp.net-core-1.1

I am using `IdentityServer4 1.0.0` with the configuration information for the clients and API resources stored in SQL Server using the `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework 1.0.0` package.

Is there a way to set a list of claims that must be present to access my API in the tables that are managed with the `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework 1.0.0` package?

Comment: Is it necessary to use certificate in identity server 4 because i am getting this error :Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:33132/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Answer (score 0):

In your API startup

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SecurePolicyName", policyUser =>
            {
                policyUser.RequireClaim("role", "admin");
            });
        });
```

Then in your controller use Auhtorize Attribute with your policy.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SecurePolicyName")]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm looking how to do the same thing but utilizing the existing IdentityServer4 object model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,  the weird thing was the claims that I've added was present in access token, but the secured API was refusing it. What you need to do is to add the claims to your client, suppose we have this API:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize("Founder")]
[Route("api/ApiResourceWithPolicy")]
public class ApiResourceWithPolicyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { ResourceType = "With Policy", ResourceName = "Api2" });
    }
}
```

And this policy setup in your startup.cs:

```
ervices.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Founder", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Employee", "Mosalla")));
```

Now add the necessary claims to your client, the important point here is to set the `ClientClaimsPrefix` to empty string:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client1",

                // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                // secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("123654".Sha256())
                },

                // scopes that client has access to
                AllowedScopes = {"Api1"},
                Claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim("Employee", "Mosalla"),
                    new Claim("website", "http://hamidmosalla.com")
                },
                ClientClaimsPrefix = ""
            }
   }
```

That's because IdentityServer4 prefixes the claims and make them unrecognizable to the resource server:

[image]

If you need more explanation visit [my post about policy-based authorization with IdentityServer4](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/12/07/policy-based-authorization-using-asp-net-core-2-identityserver4).

Comment: how to make sure the claim is not there?